# Reading Excel formulae using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, spreadsheet

I'm trying to use the Spreadsheet gem to parse XLS files that store information about school courses. These XLS files are automatically generated, so I cannot change the presentation of data.

Course schedules are saved as a list of characters, with dashes representing days in which the class does not meet. An example would be "3--33--", meaning the class meets during block 3 on days 1, 4, and 5 in the rotation. Excel parses some of these schedules as formulae, meaning that I need to read the formula itself from certain cells.
The problem is that when I try to read the data from a formula cell, using cell.data, the result is a string like `\r\x00\x1F\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xD0\x84\xC0\x1EB\x00\x04`. I'm assuming that this is Ruby's attempt to print the data as ASCII text. After some research, I have learned that Excel stores formulae in RPN format.

In short: I'm not sure how to go about reading a formula (the formula itself, not the formula's calculated value) from an Excel spreadsheet. I can't change the input Excel spreadsheet, and having a purely Ruby solution would be nice, since I'm planning on using this with Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach is:

- convert it to csv using xls2csv: http://linux.die.net/man/1/xls2csv
- read it using the ruby standard lib: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

I hope this can help you.

Comment: I was hoping for a pure Ruby solution, but this way works too. Thank you!